# Difference between "curl -XPUT --data-binary @${file_path}" and "curl -XPUT -T ${file_path}"?

Tags: curl

While using curl to POST or PUT a file to a url, there are two different ways to load the file content:

1. `-T ${file_path}`
2. `--data-binary @${file_path}` or `-d $@{file_path}` (for ascii data files)

What is the difference between these two options?

Answer (score 2):

To understand differences between these options, you can either read the [man page](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html) or make some experiments.

### The man page

> -d, --data
>
> Sends the specified data in a **POST** request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML
> form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the
> data to the server using the **content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded**. [...]
>
> -T, --upload-file
>
> This transfers the specified local file to the remote URL. [...] If this is used on an HTTP(S) server, the **PUT** command will be used.
> [...]

### Make some experiments

Run netcat in listening mode (macOS version):

```
nc -l localhost 8989
```

Create a test file:

```
echo test>test
```

Run the curl commands and check the results on the listening side:

```
% curl -d "name=test" localhost:8989

POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8989
User-Agent: curl/7.84.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 9
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

name=test


% curl -T test localhost:8989

PUT /test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8989
User-Agent: curl/7.84.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 5
Expect: 100-continue

test
```

To answer your question, the `-d` option make a POST request by sending the data with the x-www-form-urlencoded format, and `-T` send a PUT request without formatting the data.